# WiFiルータと統合型ルータを繋げインターネットを利用することは可能でしょうか

Tags: network

勉強用にCisco統合型ルータを購入しました。自宅のインターネットはモデム→WiFiルータ(有線/無線)で利用しています。Wifiルータと統合型ルータを繋げインターネットを利用することは可能でしょうか。

#### 環境

- 以下でインターネット接続
  モデム(LANポート)⇔WiFiルータ(WANポート)
- WiFiルータからは無線でPCを利用中

#### 実現したいこと

WiFiルータと統合型ルータを繋げ、さらに統合型ルータのLANポートにPCを接続し、インターネットに出たい

#### 機器環境

モデム：LANポート1口のみ
WiFiルータ：WANポートは1口のみ。LANポートは4口あり
統合型ルータ：WANポート2口(GE/FE)、LANポート8口

初心者ですみません。解決のためにどうかよろしくお願いします。

Comment: まずは製品マニュアル等を確認すべき内容かと思います。

Comment: 確認した上での質問です。

Answer (score 1):

オイラたち読者からすると型番も何もわからないので答えようがない、ってのが正直なところなわけですが

その Cisco の統合型ルータとあなたの使っている Wifi ルータとはほぼ同じ機能を持っていることが推測されます。んで、勉強のためならば俗にいう二重ルータは邪魔なだけなので（両方を正しく設定できるのなら既に理解済みってこと）どっちかを無効にしたくなります。 Cisco ルータの勉強をしたいのに Cisco ルータを無効にしてもしかたないので WiFi ルータの機能のうちの「ルータ部」を無効にする必要がありそうです。要するに単なるアクセスポイントモードにする、ってこと。逆に `PPPoE` 機能を Cisco ルータ側で有効にする正しくアカウント設定する、ことができないと ISP の認証が通りません。

あと一言でモデムと言い切っちゃっていますが実は単純 ONU だったりルータ機能付き ONU だったりする可能性がある（が読者にはわからない）ので、もしかしたらこっちのルータ機能も無効にする必要があるかもしれません。

というわけで

- PPPoE などのアカウント認証をどの機器でするか決めて正しく設定する
- ルータ機能を持つ機器が複数ある状況と推定されるので、１個だけ有効にして他は無効にする（当然 Cisco ルータ有効にする）
- 無線が必要なら WiFi ルータをアクセスポイントモードにする
  最初は無線に手を出さずに有線オンリーのほうがおすすめ
- 正しく設定できるまで Flets 光電話とか使えないかもしれないけど大丈夫？

「可能か？」という質問に対する答えは「可能でしょう」となります。そこまで自力でたどり着けるかどうかは話は別。もしかしたら現在の機器ではできなくて買い替えが必要かもしれません。

ルータ機能を下手に無効化すると、たとえ一時的であっても The Internet 上を常時流れている無差別攻撃通信からあなたの PC を保護できなくなって、踏み台にされる→各種犯罪行為があなたの IP アドレスから行われる、みたいなことになりかねないです。そういうリスクは想定しておいてください。

---

どうしても実機という条件からは外れますがシミュレータでちょっと勉強してから実機に手を出してもよいかもしれないっスね。 Cisco Packet Tracer とか評判よさそうです。日本語解説記事もいっぱい見つかりますし。無料ですけどユーザー登録は必要なので直リンクは無し。

実機を使う場合も、クラックされて構わない別の PC を１台用意し（ネットワークセグメント分離の勉強ならもう１台あると便利）普段使いの PC は実験ネットからは物理分離すると安心。 4G/5G 携帯電話回線＋スマホによるテザリングとかあれば完璧っス。

コメント中の Q はコメント欄で続けるにはもったいないので新規質問にしていただくと皆が喜ぶでしょう。オイラよりネットワークに詳しい人がいくらでも答えてくれる（あるいはツッコミを入れる）でしょう。

Comment: 詳細にありがとうございます。

Cisco統合型ルータの型番は「891FJ-K9」です。
モデムにはルーター機能が無く、Wifiルータはルーティング機能ON、APモードONにしております。

この質問の意図は、Wifiルーター配下で今回購入した統合型ルータを利用してルーティングやセキュリティの勉強をしたいということです。

おっしゃられる通り不慣れなのであちこちいじっていると予期せぬトラブルを起こしかねないので安全なWifiルーター配下でどうにかルーティングの勉強ができないか思案している状況です。例えばWifiルータのLANポートと統合型ルータのLANポートを繋げて且つ同VLANを他のポートにも設定し、そこに有線でPCをつないでPCからWAN側に出れないかなど考えましたが、そもそもそんなことできるのかもわからず。。

もし私の実現したいことに足りない機器や、認識があればご教示いただきたいです。
NWエンジニアとして実機を使って学んで行きたいのでどうかアドバイスをお願いします。